# ReactiveUI "Compelling Example" how to refresh the search results

Tags: wpf, reactive-programming, reactiveui

My question is in regards to the "Compelling Example" given for ReactiveUI where as a person types in a search bar, the search occurs asynchronously. Suppose though I wanted to provide my user with a way to refresh the current search results. I could just ask them to backspace in the search bar and retype their last character. However, they are asking for a "Refresh" button because it's not obvious to them how to refresh the current results.

I can't think of how to do this within the context of the example:

```
public class TheViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private string query;

    private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<List<string>> matches;

    public TheViewModel()
    {
        var searchEngine = this.ObservableForProperty(input => input.Query)
                .Value()
                .DistinctUntilChanged()
                .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(800))
                .Where(query => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query) && query.Length > 1);

        var search = searchEngine.SelectMany(TheSearchService.DoSearchAsync);

        var latestResults =
            searchEngine.CombineLatest(search, (latestQuery, latestSearch) => latestSearch.Query != latestQuery ? null : latestSearch.Matches)
                .Where(result => result != null);

        matches = latestResults.ToProperty(this, result => result.Matches);
    }

    public string Query
    {
        get
        {
            return query;
        }
        set
        {
            this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref query, value);
        }
    }

    public List<string> Matches
    {
        get
        {
            return matches.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could capture a command from a button and re-execute the existing search without clearing out their current search text?

Answer (score 1):

You can merge the existing observable of `Query` changes with a new observable that returns the current `Query` when the refresh button is pressed.

First a command for the refresh button:

```
public ReactiveCommand<Unit, String> Refresh { get; private set; }
```

Then you create the command and assign it, and create a merged observable of the two observables:

```
Refresh = ReactiveCommand.Create<Unit, String>(() => Query);

var searchEngine = Observable.Merge(
    this.ObservableForProperty(input => input.Query).Value().DistinctUntilChanged(),
    Refresh)
        .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(800))
        .Where(query => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query) && query.Length > 1);
```

The rest can stay unchanged.